# Qt Creator Javascript ES6 syntax not supported?

Tags: javascript, qt, ecmascript-6, qt-creator

I'm a c++ person tragically tasked with a bit of web development.

Qt Creator 4.9.2 (the latest) seems not to like ES6 modules.

```
import {Something} from './something.js';

export class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;

        this.callback = () => {
            console.log("hi");
        }

            let h = 1;
    }
}
```

The import statement and "export class" lines generate a bunch of M127 warnings.

More annoyingly lines after an arrow function and certain other constructs are incorrectly indented, like "let h = 1" above.

Qt itself should support ES6 since version 5.12 so it seems like Creator would as well.  Is this expected behavior?  Some newbie mistake on my part?  Maybe I need to find some custom syntax description?